# Text alignment different for different languages in IE6

Tags: html, css, cjk

I have a pagination bar, which holds the page items. And our application have to support i18n. Then we found out that the text can not align as expected when displaying Chinese language.

[Example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/bNPXz/)

And here is the result of [ff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z2Er.png) and [ie6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Giqkj.png).

Note that in IE6, the `下一页` `li` can not align with other `li`. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The markup and especially the styling is too complicated for old versions of IE, and trying to fix the style tends to lead to further complications and a non-robust solution. So if you would rather solve the problem than “do things right”, here’s a robust approach in markup:

```
<table align=center class=page>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="...">Next</a>
        <td><a href="...">1</a>
        <td><a href="...">下一页</a>
</table>
```

This can easily be fine-tuned regarding padding, font, colors, etc., in CSS....

You would still have problems on IE 6, since it was quite often installed without Chinese language support. An out-of-the-box PC with IE 6 used to display Chinese characters as small rectangles, due to lack of suitable fonts.

Comment: can you tell me which style is complicated?

Answer (score 2):

Change from:

```
.page li
{
    display: inline;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

to:

```
.page li
{
    display: inline;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Another problem with IE is that if you comment out the line (with preceding '#'), it still picks up the parameter. Its a stupid bug. so delete the line instead of commenting it.

Comment: No effect, when tested on IE 6 in an XP virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

```
.page ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height:40px;
}
.page li
{
    display: inline;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    line-height:40px;
}
:first-child + html .page li a
{
    margin-right: 0px;
}
.page a, .page a:visited, .page a:active
{
    border: 1px solid #9AAFE5;
    color: #2E6AB1;
   padding: 5px 0.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height:40px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bNPXz/19/)